# Connecting to a user defined docker bridge network

Tags: docker, redis, docker-network, redis-cluster

I tried creating a Redis cluster using docker by following the tutorial [here](https://simplydistributed.wordpress.com/2018/08/31/redis-5-bootstrapping-a-redis-cluster-with-docker/).
The script given creates the cluster using Redis 5 docker image and by creating nodes in a custom docker bridge network.
I am able to connect to the cluster through redis-cli but when I try to connect to a node through a golang program I am not able to do so and I get connection refused error. I am connecting to the "localhost:port" where port is the port number that has been exposed during creation of nodes by docker run command.

```
docker run -d --name "redis-"$port -p $port:6379 --net $network_name $redis_image $start_cmd;
```

Any pointers to do so will be really helpful.